# How to fix Tomcat issue not working with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9, catalina

Tomcat is not working with Eclipse. 
I tried everything from changing port number to admin port number.
cleaned the directory.
restarted multiple times
cleaned the project, reloaded, restarted, done every possible research.

- Actually tomcat starts, console shows no error. but tomcat's welcome page doesn't appear.
- When run manually going to C:program files/apache_tomcat/tomcat9/bin, it runs from here but not on eclipse.

Type Status Report
Message /spring-mvc-demo/
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

- Logs

  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.33
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Server built:          Mar 11 2020 09:31:38 UTC
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Server version number: 9.0.33.0
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: OS Version:            10.0
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Architecture:          amd64
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_221-b11
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\Eclipse_Projects\Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\Eclipse_Projects\Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\Eclipse_Projects\Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
  INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\atom\bin;E:\Eclipse_Projects\eclipse;;.]
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7878"]
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
  INFO: Server initialization in [1,319] milliseconds
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
  INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
  INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
  INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7878"]
  Mar 30, 2020 11:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
  INFO: Server startup in [481] milliseconds

Comment: The Welcome is its own web app. Are you deploying it along with your own?

Comment: I meant tomcat's welcome page, it appear when tomcat is running and go to url  http://localhost:8080/..
On my eclipse it runs fine with out any error in logs while tomcat's welcome page does not appear when we go to local host url localhost:8080/ on both eclipse browser as well chrome or any other browser.

Comment: I know. It normally arrives in the folder named ROOT in the Tomcat web apps folder. It is a web app.